# Get Selected Value from SfRadioButton in xamarin MVVM

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, radio-button, syncfusion

i want to get the value of the selected radio button in my viewModel using syncfusion radio button so i can do some logics based on the value selected. i cant seem to get the selected value. please help!

Xaml

```
<syncfusion:SfRadioGroup x:Name="radioGroup"
      BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <syncfusion:SfRadioButton 
                      Text="{Binding PaymentMethod}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </syncfusion:SfRadioGroup>
```

View Model

```
 public List<PaymentMthd> Items { get; set; }



Items = new List<PaymentMthd>()

{

new PaymentMthd(){PaymentMethod = "Cash" , id = 1},

new PaymentMthd(){PaymentMethod = "Visa Card" , id = 2},



};

private int _IsChecked;



public int IsChecked

{

get { return _IsChecked; }

set { SetProperty(ref _IsChecked, value); }
```

Comment: according to the docs, `SfRadioGroup` has a `CheckedItem` property

Comment: Could it work now ?

Comment: You can achieve your requirement “Get the value of selected radio button” with the help of StateChanged event. For more details, please refer the below KB document. [https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/11037/how-to-notify-the-selection-changes-in-xamarin-forms-radiobutton-sfradiobutton](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/11037/how-to-notify-the-selection-changes-in-xamarin-forms-radiobutton-sfradiobutton)

Answer (score 1):

You could add the [StateChanged](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/radio-button/event#statechanged-event) event to listen the state.

```
<syncfusion:SfRadioButton 
                  Text="{Binding PaymentMethod}" StateChanged="RadioButton_StateChanged" />
```

then in your code behind:

```
private void RadioButton_StateChanged(object sender, StateChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.IsChecked.HasValue && e.IsChecked.Value)
  {
     //if checked,do something
  }
  else if (e.IsChecked.HasValue && !e.IsChecked.Value)
  {
    //if not checked,do something
  }
}
```

You can also use the `CheckedChanged` event to get the selected RadioButton in RadioGroup, which has been invoked while changing the selection in the RadioGroup.

```
<syncfusion:SfRadioGroup x:Name="radioGroup" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
               CheckedChanged="CheckedChanged_event">
  <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <syncfusion:SfRadioButton Text="{Binding PaymentMethod}" />
            </DataTemplate>
  </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</syncfusion:SfRadioGroup>
```

in your code behind:

```
 private void CheckedChanged_event(object sender,Syncfusion.XForms.Buttons.CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
 { 
   // To get the selected RadioButton - e.CurrentItem
  // To get the previously selected RadioButton -  e.PreviousItem
 }
```